# Oracle SQL - Variable between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I cannot figure out why this code will not work. It is a bit backwards, which may be confusing me.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(  
 SELECT   
 TO_CHAR(FTPRITIN.start_date, 'DD-MON-YY') start_date,
 TO_CHAR(FTPRITIN.end_date, 'DD-MON-YY') end_date 
 FROM ftpritin 
)
WHERE :VARIABLE BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

I have also tried

```
SELECT * FROM 
(  
 SELECT   
 TO_CHAR(FTPRITIN.start_date, 'DD-MON-YY') start_date,
 TO_CHAR(FTPRITIN.end_date, 'DD-MON-YY') end_date 
 FROM ftpritin 
)
WHERE start_date > :VARIABLE AND end_date < :VARIABLE
```

But it does not seem to work. The query runs but grabs data completely out of the range.

What i need is to grab data rows where the variable falls between the start_date and end_date. Any ideas? Any help is much appreciated.

**ANSWER**

FYI - For those who wonder why such an easy problem was so hard - Or for those who have a similar problem...

The field was a **TIMESTAMP** and not a date field. I figured this out by running

`DESC table_name`

Then i just did a quick substr to_date to fix it

`to_date(substr(start_date, 1, 9))`

This allowed me to filter by date

`WHERE to_date(substr(start_date, 1, 9)) <= to_date(:VARIABLE, 'DD-MON-YY')...`

Thanks for the help everyone.

(Less than 10 rep so i cant answer my own post)

Answer (score 2):

Your date formats are in the wrong order.  But, why can't you just do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ftpritin 
WHERE start_date > :VARIABLE AND end_date < :VARIABLE
```

Where `:VARIABLE` is a date/datetime?  Or, if it has to be a string:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ftpritin 
WHERE start_date > to_date(:VARIABLE, <right format goes here>) AND
      end_date < to_date(:VARIABLE, <right format goes here>)
```

Comment: Im not a pro at databases, but to_date() wouldn't work on these fields, thats why i used to_char().

Comment: If the field is already a date, using to_date() is unnecessary.  However, if the variable is a string, using to_date() on it seems like a good idea.

Comment: Is this not backwards? I want my variable to be between start_date and end_date. start_date will always be earlier on the calendar than end_date, so wouldn't it be `start_date < to_date(var) AND end_date > to_date(var)` ?

Comment: FYI - For those who wonder why such an easy problem was so hard - Or for those who have a similar problem... 

The field was a **TIMESTAMP** and not a date field. I figured this out by running

`DESC table_name`

Then i just did a quick substr to_date to fix it

`to_date(substr(start_date, 1, 9))`

This allowed me to filter by date

`WHERE to_date(substr(start_date, 1, 9)) <= to_date(:VARIABLE, 'DD-MON-YY')...`

Thanks for the help everyone. 

(Less than 10 rep so i cant answer my own post)

Comment: @CadeWard . . . The logic for the condition was taken from your question.